# Caching WebBrowser control between open/close of app

Tags: .net, winforms, caching, webbrowser-control

Is there a way to persist the cache of a WebBrowser control in between runs of a WinForms application.  The WinForm application is basically a simplified browser that goes to a page depending on command line arguments.

It seems to cache pages while running so I can quickly go forward and back, but I would also like to cache these pages so that the first load of the application is quick.  It doesn't seem to do this be default.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could pre-load the content and set the `WebbrowserControl.DocumentText` property , thus avoiding the web round trip .

If you mean pre loading the WebBrowserControl control itself , I can only think about using the GAC for that (Global Assembly Cache). Even though chances are that all framework assemblies are already GACed.

For more info please see:
[Global Assembly Cache Tool (Gacutil.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)   
and 
[WebBrowser.DocumentText Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx)